# Encoding Bipartite Matching as a special case of Independent Set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

> Given a bipartite graph $G' = (V', E')$, the objects being chosen are edges, and the conflicts arise between two edges that share an end. (These, indeed, are the pairs of edges that cannot belong to a common matching.) So we define a graph $G = (V, E)$ in which the node set $V$ is equal to the edge set $E'$ of $G'$. We define an edge between each pair of elements in $V$ that correspond to edges of $G'$ with a common end. We can now check that the independent sets of $G$ are precisely the matchings of $G'$.

I am trying to understand the quote above.

Suppose there are two pairs $(x, y), (y, z) \in E'$. These are edges that share a node. If these nodes are men and women, then they can't share the same partner (they are monogamous). To solve this problem we define a pair $(a, b) \in V$ and set it equivalent to the two pairs above, like so: $(x, y), (y, z) \iff (a, b).$ We see that $(a, b)$ is an edge that connects two nodes and also represents conflicting pairs. Then we can make non-conflicting pairs from all the nodes in $V$ that are not connected by an edge. These nodes make up an independent set. Am I understanding it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you have wrote, than you understand the cited paragraph ;-)

Just, in case you are not sure, here is a simple diagram that illustrates possible matchings and corresponding independent sets:

[image: possible matching]

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$